# How install npm dependency (rsuite) from github repository

Tags: github, npm, installation, rsuite

I'm using next js 11.

I want to edit an rsuite component, so I understand that I need to clone the dependency https://github.com/rsuite/rsuite.git, and in my branch make the changes and then install it.

The problem is that while I can install the dependency ("rsuite": "MYUSER/rsuite"), not all files are installed.

Test installing then directly from rsuite, ("rsuite": "rsuite/rsuite") also probe, "rsuite": "git [https://github.com/rsuite/rsuite.git"](https://github.com/rsuite/rsuite.git%22) and other ways, (npm install https://github.com/rsuite/rsuite.git) and (yarn add https://github.com/rsuite/rsuite.git), but there is no case, not everything is installed, only some files.

Does anyone know how they could do it?

Thanks a lot.

image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because npm installation will read the information in package.json.

```
npm install https://github.com/rsuite/rsuite.git
```

The [package.json](https://github.com/rsuite/rsuite/blob/main/package.json#L71-L75) files configuration is read when the above statement is executed.

So only the README and CHANGELOG files are available. In order to make it more convenient to import components in a modular manner, rsuite adopts the following methods to import.

```js
import Button rsuite/Button
```

To implement such component import, we make a custom directory when rsuite is released. All components will be copied to the root directory and associated with the cjs and esm directories through soft links. Detailed release scripts can be viewed in the [gulpfile](https://github.com/rsuite/rsuite/blob/main/scripts/gulpfile.js) configuration.